# Does Service starts automatically?

Tags: android

I have a service that has started by startService and binded with BIND_AutoCreate , I want my service runs automatically when android kill it for low memory , how can I implant that  ?

thanks'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service is created because of the **BIND_AUTO_CREATE** binding, it will be stopped if it does not have any activities bound to it.

According to the docs ([service lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)), you can both start explicitly a service and then bind with the autocreate flag enabled.

If you start explicitly the service as STICKY (returning START_STICKY in its * onStartCommand* method, it will be automatically restarted back whenever the system has more resources.

Comment: I have did it , It seem that there is a bug in android device .

Answer (score 0):

You have to register broadcast receiver for the `ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_OK` which indicates low memory condition on the device no longer exists. In the `onReceive()` method check your service if it is stopped, start it.

The `DEVICE_STORAGE_OK` action is broadcast when the device has recovered from a low memory state(internal memory). I think this is a perfect event for you to check if your service was killed during memory recovery by the system, and start it if was killed.

Please read [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_OK).

Comment: I have not slept for days.. Whats the issue?

Comment: when internal phone is low , android will kill process , not when storage is low.

Comment: The `DEVICE_STORAGE_OK` action is broadcast when the device has recovered from a low memory state(internal memory). I think this is a perfect event for you to check if your service was killed during memory recovery by the system, and start it if was killed.

Comment: How did you do it? Was this helpful?

Comment: the problem is here I do want it to start itself , if it's killed , do you know any way ?

Comment: Did you try as suggested by fedepaol's answer? - using STICKY? Service does not start by itself?

Comment: I read the doc abt STICKY. It does not apply to your case. The system will try to re-create the service only if  this service's process is killed while it is started. Not otherwise.